# If you see the "cross", you're on the right track

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

### I'm looking for a specific phrase. Try to find it!

---

```
          *         **
         
          ***       ****
          *****     ******


          Q S  N P  D F   
          S U  S U  E G   
          L N  R T  N P   
          U W  E G  D F 

    

    [S][Q][H][E][L][G][O][M][W]
    [Y][V][B][T][S][B][M][N][J]
    [C][X][G][R][J][O][L][M][K]
    [T][V][H][P][L][P][A][I][N]
    [A][J][B][C][E][A][H][E][G]
    [A][N][O][D][S][B][T][P][O]
    [R][T][S][F][H][A][W][I][N]
    [U][F][I][D][J][I][W][T][L]
    [H][K][N][C][P][E][U][A][R]
    [L][S][A][I][M][N][H][E][I]
    [W][E][R][G][B][I][R][O][K]
    [R][C][V][T][W][O][J][B][U]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for is

> **SHAPED INTO A NET OF A DICE**.

First, we realize that,

> the stars are grouped into six categories and they probably indicate numbers 1-6. And the mini-grid cosists of 12 pairs of letters where we can put a letter amidst each pair following the alphabetical order.
>
> ```
> Q(R)S  N(O)P  D(E)F
>
> S(T)U  S(T)U  E(F)G
>
> L(M)N  R(S)T  N(O)P
>
> U(V)W  E(F)G  D(E)F
> ```

Considering these two facts we further conclude that,

> this mini-grid represents a cube-net.
>
> ```
>        N(1)P
>
> S(2)U  S(3)U  E(5)G
>
>        R(6)T
>
>        E(4)G
> ```
>
> Or specifically, a net of a die.
>
> <sup>(The rest of the grid was erased because those letters spelled 'REMOVE')</sup>

So that's the cross, and we are on the right track!

> Now we move onto the big-grid and divide it into regions as below.
>
> ```
> [S][Q][H] [E][L][G] [O][M][W]
> [Y][V][B] [T][S][B] [M][N][J]
> [C][X][G] [R][J][O] [L][M][K]
>
> [T][V][H] [P][L][P] [A][I][N]
> [A][J][B] [C][E][A] [H][E][G]
> [A][N][O] [D][S][B] [T][P][O]
>
> [R][T][S] [F][H][A] [W][I][N]
> [U][F][I] [D][J][I] [W][T][L]
> [H][K][N] [C][P][E] [U][A][R]
>
> [L][S][A] [I][M][N] [H][E][I]
> [W][E][R] [G][B][I] [R][O][K]
> [R][C][V] [T][W][O] [J][B][U]
> ```

and

> extract the letters in the corresponding 'dots' on the faces of a die.
>
> ```
>           [E][L][G]
>           [T][S][B]
>           [R][J][O]
>
> [T][V][H] [P][L][P] [A][I][N]
> [A][J][B] [C][E][A] [H][E][G]
> [A][N][O] [D][S][B] [T][P][O]
>
>           [F][H][A]
>           [D][J][I]
>           [C][P][E]
>
>           [I][M][N]
>           [G][B][I]
>           [T][W][O]
> ```
>
> S/HA/PED/ANETO/FADICE/INTO
>
> We get the solution by reordering them according to the face values of the die.

Comment: I'm guessing that the mini grid contains the hint to look into the source code, probably.

Comment: Haha wow, well that was completely unintentional... The source. I'm surprised I forgot to delete it. Your answer is ofc correct, but regarding the mini-grid try to make sense of it.. think rot13(va orgjrra)

Comment: Haha :D @Prim3numbah, I adjusted my answer to fit the intended solution path. But not sure why you included that picture. :P

Comment: Great! Looks good now, well done. I added that picture so that I could compare the grid of the puzzle with the intended net, wanted to see the both on the same page. Using phone and not computer so a bit more messy.